# jQuery Trouble triggering click event on popup

Tags: html, jquery, eventtrigger

I have a fairly simple page with a couple divs designed to be pop ups...

I'm having an issue with the `.close` div located in a jQuery populated popup. A btn is clicked .. jquery brings up a div and then populates it with content from another div.

This all works as expected.

There's a `.close` div in the popups designed to be, well a close button.

```
$('body, .close').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#info').html('').removeClass('pop').fadeOut(300);
    $('#pup').children('h1').html('');
    $('#pup').fadeOut(300);
    $('#cov').fadeOut(300);
    console.log('clk');
});
```

This works *perfectly* when the `.close` div is hard coded into the popup itself.. but it will **not** function in the when content is populated from somewhere else.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing please?

---

```js
// included so snippet functions....
var cards = $(".smpl");
cards.each(function(i) {
  var im = $(this).attr('data-im');
  var fadeTime = 180;
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(_core/img/p/' + im + ')')
  $(this).delay(fadeTime * i).fadeIn(fadeTime);
});

// loaded #info with content from other divs
$('.about, .cont').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var wht = $(this).attr('data-t');
  $('#info').removeClass('pop').html(''); //empty's info popup if its present
  $('#pup').hide(); //hides other popup if its present
  $('#cov').fadeIn(300);
  $('#info').addClass('pop').html($(wht).html()).fadeIn(300);
  console.log(wht);
});

// Should close all popups - FAIL for the #info .close div
// ###### this is where something is not right or borken...
$('body, .close').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#info').html('').removeClass('pop').fadeOut(300);
  $('#pup').children('h1').html('');
  $('#pup').fadeOut(300);
  $('#cov').fadeOut(300);
  console.log('clk');
});

$('#info').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#pup').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});

//This opens #pup div
$('.sp, .ai, .ot').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var imgsrc = $(this).attr('data-im');
  var longDes = $(this).children('.dspt').attr('data-ld');
  $('#cov').fadeIn(300);
  $('#pup').addClass('pop');
  $('#pup h1').html(longDes);
  $('#pup').css('background-image', 'url(_core/img/p/' + imgsrc + ')').fadeIn(300);
});
```

```css
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 9997;
}

.nav a:link,
.nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  width: 76px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #07e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 #fff;
}

.smpl {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc((100% - 60px) / 10);
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background: #aaa;
}

h1.dspt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.smpl:hover h1.dspt {
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: #07e;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#over,
#cov {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #aaa;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9991;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#cov {
  background: #fffs;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#pup,
#info {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  z-index: 9998;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 50px #666;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

#pup h1.dspt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 1px #000;
}

#pup:hover h1.dspt {
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#info {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-Y: auto;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.pop .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: -40px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .5;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pop:hover .close {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#about,
#cont {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cov"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="pup">
  <h1 class="dspt"></h1>
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 cell masthead">
      <div class="base">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#" class="nbtn about" data-t="#about">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nbtn cont" data-t="#cont">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 cell" id="content">
      <div id="about">
        <div class="close">X</div>
        <h4>about - Info Div</h4>
        <p>Hover to see close btn, but it fails to function.
          <p>
      </div>
      <div id="cont">
        <div class="close">X</div>
        <p>Contact - Info div</p>
        <p>Hover to see close btn, but it fails to function.
          <p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 cell inner">
          <div class="smpl sp" data-im="h1pc_15px.png">
            <div class="zm"></div>
            <h1 class="dspt" data-ld="#pup div">Pup Div</h1>
            <img alt="H" src="_core/img/p/_blank.png"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- // grid padding -->
</div>
<!-- //grid container -->
```

#### Snippet Above ..

- If you click the [broken] image
- the `#pup` popup shows
- clicking outside `#pup`(grey area) removes the popup (- GOOD)
- clicking the `.close` div removes the popup (- GOOD).

---

- Click "about" or "contact" in the header
- the `#info` popup shows
- clicking *outside* that popup (grey area) closes it (- GOOD)
- clicking the `.close` div simply *won't* trigger the close event (- **FAIL**).

---

Suggested that it was due to the click event on `body` and stopPropagation... So I tested...

```
$('.about, .cont').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    var wht = $(this).attr('data-t');
    $('#info').removeClass('pop').html(''); //empty's info popup if its present
    $('#pup').hide(); //hides other popup if its present
    $('#cov').fadeIn(300);
    $('#info').addClass('pop').html($(wht).html()).fadeIn(300);
    console.log(wht);
    });

$('#cov, .close').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    $('#info').html('').removeClass('pop').fadeOut(300);
    $('#pup').children('h1').html('');
    $('#pup').fadeOut(300);
    $('#cov').fadeOut(300);
    console.log('clk');
});
```

Issue remains.

Comment: may you add a Code Snippet in question? this way, we can investigate and find out your problem.

Comment: Snippet Added and question reworded

Comment: that's because you're stopping the event propagation when a click occur on `div#pup` and `div#info`.

Comment: @ths If I comment out stopProp on the close event, the issue remains. If I comment out stopProp on the trigger event to *open* the popup... `#info` opens then immediately closes.

Comment: Because you have set to close the popup on `body` clicks.

Comment: I can see that reasoning.. but see question update....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you change the click function to: `$(document).on('click', 'body', '.close', function()`

You also need to remove this bit:

```
$('#info').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#pup').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes just need another pair of eyes. Much appreciated! `:)`